# Combinatorics questions about balls in boxes

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

20 indistinguishable balls are to be placed in 5 distinguishable boxes. In how many ways can this be done if exactly one box should have no balls an at least one box should have at least 11 balls?

For context, this is what I've tried but it's been wrong.

5C1 x (9+4-1)C(4-1)

Comment: What have you tried? Please give a bit more context.

Comment: Choose which box gets no balls.  Recognize that only one box can receive at least $11$ balls since there are so few balls to place.  Choose which box that is and put $10$ balls in it for now.  Now, distribute the remaining $10$ balls across the $4$ not-designated-to-be-empty boxes subject to the constraint that each receive at least one.  This last step is a standard problem-type solved by stars-and-bars.

Comment: Your attempt is almost correct.  You have neglected to account for the "*exactly one box should have none*" condition correctly or you have neglected to account for the "*at least one should have at least 11*" condition correctly, making your answer off by a factor of $4$.  You only designated one box, not two, to have special purpose.  Further, after putting $10$ (*not 11*) balls into the designated box, you still have $10$ (*not 9*) balls remaining, so you are off by one there as well.  Your binomial coefficient would have been for if we have strictly greater than $11$ balls, not $\geq$

Comment: @JMoravitz to make sure I account that only one box should be empty, does that mean I should only be left with 6 balls to distribute? One box is empty, one gets 11, and the other 3 get one each, which leaves us with 6 for the latter 4 boxes. Does that mean it's 5C1 * (6+4-1)C(4-1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose which box gets no balls. Recognize that only one box can receive at least 11 balls since there are so few balls to place. Choose which box that is and put 10 balls in it for now. Now, distribute the remaining 10 balls across the 4 not-designated-to-be-empty boxes subject to the constraint that each receive at least one. This last step is a standard problem-type solved by stars-and-bars.

So, first, we choose which box is empty.  We have $5$ choices.  (*Note... we don't bother writing this as $\binom{5}{1}$ since $\binom{n}{1}$ is always just simply equal to $n$.  Don't use excessive notation when there is no benefit to doing so.*)

Next, we choose which box will be greatly filled.  We have $4$ remaining choices.  We go ahead and place $10$ balls in this box for now.  We only place $10$ because we will soon be placing at least one more here and it is convenient for maintaining the symmetry that all remaining not-designated-to-be-empty boxes all require at least one more ball.

Now, we are in the position of having four boxes each needing at least one more ball and $10$ balls to place.  We distribute these balls according to [stars-and-bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) in $\binom{10-1}{4-1}=\binom{9}{3}$ ways

The final answer is then:

$$5\times 4\times \binom{9}{3}$$

Alternatively, if you preferred, rather than giving $10$ balls to the box designated to receive many, go ahead and give $11$ balls to it ahead of time.  Further, give one ball to each of the other remaining three boxes.  Now we are in the pattern where each of the four not-designated-to-be-empty boxes need $0$ or more additional balls and $6$ additional balls to place, the other standard problem type for stars-and-bars.  In such an explanation we have $\binom{6+4-1}{4-1}=\binom{9}{3}$ ways to do this, same as before, going to the same final answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was really struggling and this finally made me get it. I think the main thing I was missing that I forgot to choose one of the 4 remaining boxes, so I kept getting 420 instead of 1680. Thank you so much!